# PostgreSQL: error with pg_hba.conf entries

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database I set up on a remote machine.

I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.X.XXX.XX", user "postgres", database "XXXXX", SSL off
```

I tried to modify the pg_hba.conf file by adding the following line:

```
host    all    all   X.X.XXX.XX/32    trust
```

(where X.X.XXX.XX is the ip address of the client)

and also the postgresql.conf file by adding

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

But I still get the same error message.

When running the database locally, however, it works.

I am running the database (Postgres 9.3) on a Mac.
The client is on another Mac, running Java with JDBC.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.
Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to change the `x.x.xxx.x` to `all` or `0.0.0.0`, and why are you trying to do that!? it's unlogical! do you get a random ip each second?!

Comment: You can be pretty sure /32 is not the network mask of your server IP, try to use /24 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Did you reload configuration with pg_ctl reload?